# MPMoviePlayerController Customization

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I set `MPMoviePlayerController` to these bounds `[moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 320, 320,78)];`

Now when playing a sound file, I am not able to getting the Done button. I am playing the sound file but am unable to `removeFromSuperview` the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view manually.

How do I remove the `MPMoviePlayerController`'s view from its superview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this code we can set the background of MPMoviePlayer -

```
moviePlayerController.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg2.png"]];
```

Comment: thanks and how to set the small size like audio player for my mpmovieplayer